# does xcode 9 compile my iOS app differently?

Tags: ios, xcode

The WhirlyGlobe-Maply mapping API I use in my iOS app, has stopped working with the upgrade to xcode 9.  Does xcode 9 introduce any build settings, or anything else, which would affect the way my app is compiled?  I have changed nothing in the code, but when xcode 9 compiles it, the vectors drawn at close zoom levels have lost their accuracy in the Y axis.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 introduces iOS 11 and unless you manually download a simulator for iOS 10, when you run your app you will be testing it on the latest and greatest from Apple.  It is that new version of iOS that is likely to give you trouble.

If your WhirlyGlobe-Maply API requires internet access, you may want to double check that it is accessing its API via HTTPS, failing that you will be required to add exceptions for the App Transport Security in your Info.plist. You can learn more about ATS in this [WWDC 2016 - What's New in Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/) video.

As for rendering issues, I would suggest you open a ticket with the developer as they may have to adjust their code to work with iOS 11.

Comment: thanks for your reply!  I'm testing the app on both iOS9 and iOS11 and I get the same problem, so I don't think it's iOS related.  After doing some more digging I am starting to think it may be with how the trigonometric functions 'atan' and 'sinh' are being evaluated...